# Unable to boot from USB drive

Tags: usb, windows-8, uefi, secure-boot

I am trying to boot Ubuntu 13.10 from a USB Drive. I was expecting a regulation procedure: BIOS>BOOT-order-tweak>boot-from-USB. But it didn't work. I recently upgraded from a 7 year old laptop, and am not familiar with either UEFI or SecureBoot or how these change anything. From first impressions of what research i could do, the combination of said unfamiliar standards help avoid malware from doing there thing, help Windows to boot super fast and are compatible with newer versions of popular Linux distributions. So ideally one should be able to boot into described Linux distro from USB w/o disabling SecureBoot or enabling Legacy anything. The problem seems quite trivial, as it is not being discussed at all. What am I doing wrong? This also worries me a bit, because I was thinking of moving windows recovery to an external drive and freeing up the valuable space from my tiny SSD (and hopefully installing another OS there), and if I can't boot from USB...!!
About Linux, can anyone also let me know if installing software not provided by HP voids my warranty?

Comment: How far do you get in attempting to boot from USB?  The black grub menu screen means you have successfully securely booted (if secure boot is enabled).  Look to other problems beyond that point like video.

Comment: Do you mean that you're having problems booting an Ubuntu installation image written to a USB flash drive, or that you've installed Ubuntu to a USB flash drive and are unable to boot it? If the former, how did you write the image to the USB flash drive?

Comment: It turns out that one has to use 64bit versions of 13.10 for UEFI/SecureBoot compatibility. I didn't know that. Now I have successively booted in the EFI mode (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Identifying_if_the_computer_boots_the_HDD_in_EFI_mode), and am might be having video problems.

Answer (score 0):

following tutorial will enable a user to check if a computer system can boot from a USB device:
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/testing-your-system-for-usb-boot-compatibility/

Comment: failed to boot Memtest from USB Drive
but there is an option to boot from USB Diskette in BIOS
also the drive is recognized at boot, if I choose 'select boot medium', I get Boot Manager and EFI File as options, under EFI file I can see the USB Drive as well as the windows partition